# I messed up MySQL. Stuck at ERROR 2002 (HY000) and can't reinstall

Tags: package-management, mysql

Okay, so first off, a back story. I come from a Windows environment, and I wanted to make Ubuntu my main dev'ment env. I started off by insalling the Lamp stack and all was okay, except when I reached MySQL. I think I missed something in the installation, but I couldn't access root. After a bit of digging -- and messing with files -- it turns out I can only access `mysql>` using sudo. But I'm used to *phpmyadmin* so I wanted to install that. I did, but turns out I can't access it because I can't sudo from the login screen on my browser. That's when I really messed up.

Long story short, I tried to uninstall it all together after trying to edit the root user and got completely locked out of `mysql>` and can't get back in. I tried many solutions to completely uninstall it, but everytime I try to `apt-get install mysql-server`, it tells me that it's already installed. When I run `mysql` or `mysql -uroot` etc, I get this

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

That's because I deleted all the files.

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server` gives me this:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 275 not upgraded.

I have no idea what to try next. Help!

EDIT:

Running `sudo apt-get purge mysql*`

> isonuz@isuntuZ:~$ sudo apt-get purge mysql*
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree       
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Note, selecting 'mysqltcl' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-mmm-agent' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-mmm-tools' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-common-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.0' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.1' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-utilities' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-mmm-common' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-sandbox' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-mmm-monitor' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysqltuner' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-workbench-data' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.1' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-source-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
>   Package 'mysql-client-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-client-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-server-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-client-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-common' instead of 'mysql-common-5.6'
>   Package 'mysql-server-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-server-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-server-5.0' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-server-5.1' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-server-core-5.1' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-mmm-agent' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-mmm-common' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-mmm-monitor' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-mmm-tools' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-sandbox' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-utilities' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-workbench' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-workbench-data' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysqltcl' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysqltuner' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-source-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-testsuite' is not installed, so not removed
>   Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>   
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    dbconfig-mysql : Depends: mysql-client but it is not going to be installed or
>                              mariadb-client but it is not going to be installed or
>                              virtual-mysql-client
>   E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Running `sudo apt-get autoremove`

> isonuz@isuntuZ:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree       
>   Reading state information... Done
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 291 not upgraded.

Running `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin`

> isonuz@isuntuZ:~$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree       
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Note, selecting 'libhttp-message-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libencode-locale-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.0-cli' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'rename' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'php-common' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libaprutil1' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.0-opcache' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libcgi-fast-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libwrap0' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libhttp-date-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'perl-modules-5.22' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'liblwp-mediatypes-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libfcgi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libcgi-pm-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.0-common' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libaio1' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libio-html-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'ssl-cert' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'apache2-data' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libperl5.22' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libapr1' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-ldap' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libhtml-tagset-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.0-json' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.0-readline' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'tcpd' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'liblua5.1-0' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libhtml-template-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libtimedate-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'apache2-bin' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'apache2' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'php-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'apache2-utils' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libhtml-parser-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php7.0' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'liburi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
>   Note, selecting 'php7.0-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
>   apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3).
>   apache2-bin is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3).
>   apache2-data is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3).
>   apache2-utils is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3).
>   libaio1 is already the newest version (0.3.110-2).
>   libapache2-mod-php is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6).
>   libapr1 is already the newest version (1.5.2-3).
>   libaprutil1 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
>   libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
>   libaprutil1-ldap is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
>   libcgi-fast-perl is already the newest version (1:2.10-1).
>   libcgi-pm-perl is already the newest version (4.26-1).
>   libencode-locale-perl is already the newest version (1.05-1).
>   libfcgi-perl is already the newest version (0.77-1build1).
>   libhtml-parser-perl is already the newest version (3.72-1).
>   libhtml-tagset-perl is already the newest version (3.20-2).
>   libhtml-template-perl is already the newest version (2.95-2).
>   libhttp-date-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
>   libhttp-message-perl is already the newest version (6.11-1).
>   libio-html-perl is already the newest version (1.001-1).
>   liblua5.1-0 is already the newest version (5.1.5-8ubuntu1).
>   liblwp-mediatypes-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
>   libperl5.22 is already the newest version (5.22.1-9).
>   libtimedate-perl is already the newest version (2.3000-2).
>   liburi-perl is already the newest version (1.71-1).
>   libwrap0 is already the newest version (7.6.q-25).
>   perl is already the newest version (5.22.1-9).
>   perl-modules-5.22 is already the newest version (5.22.1-9).
>   php-common is already the newest version (1:35ubuntu6).
>   php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6).
>   rename is already the newest version (0.20-4).
>   ssl-cert is already the newest version (1.0.37).
>   tcpd is already the newest version (7.6.q-25).
>   libapache2-mod-php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1).
>   mysql-client-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1).
>   mysql-client-core-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1).
>   mysql-common is already the newest version (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1).
>   mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1).
>   mysql-server-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1).
>   mysql-server-core-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1).
>   php7.0-cli is already the newest version (7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1).
>   php7.0-common is already the newest version (7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1).
>   php7.0-json is already the newest version (7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1).
>   php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1).
>   php7.0-opcache is already the newest version (7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1).
>   php7.0-readline is already the newest version (7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1).
>   phpmyadmin is already the newest version (4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 291 not upgraded.

**<<<<  SOLVED  >>>>**

`sudo apt-get purge mysql*` wasn't completely uninstalling it, so I went crazy and did

> sudo apt-get purge *mysql * *php * *apache * *lamp * (no spacews between the word and the *)
>   sudo apt-get autoremove
>   sudo apt-get autoclean
>   sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
>   sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
>   sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext

And of course made the necessary configurations. The problem ultimately was that I was setting up mysql without a password. This works in Windows, but apparently not on Ubuntu. So I just set a password for it this time around and it all worked as it should.

Comment: You can try these commands in order `sudo apt-get purge mysql*` then `sudo apt-get autoremove` then `sudo apt-get install -f` then finally `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin`

Comment: Those did nothing.

Comment: What error did you get? You can't just say "they didn't work"

Comment: Edited my post with the output.

Comment: Try this now: `sudo apt-get purge dbconfig-mysql` then `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I got it working.  I finally completely removed it by putting *mysql* in the command. I edited my post with more info. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Tarek, kindly write down your fix as an answer using the "answer your own question" link below instead of editing it in the question. That way, we can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get purge mysql* wasn't completely uninstalling it, so I went crazy and did

`sudo apt-get purge *mysql * *php * *apache * *lamp * (no spacews between the word and the *)
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext`

And of course made the necessary configurations. The problem ultimately was that I was setting up mysql without a password. This works in Windows, but apparently not on Ubuntu. So I just set a password for it this time around and it all worked as it should.